# How can I download a file which return via an API - facing Deserialising error byte[] to string

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, pdf-generation, blazor-webassembly

I want to generate a pdf and download using a POST API.
I am working on .net blazor webAssembly.

My endpoint return a pdf file.

```
     public async Task<IResult> HandleAsync(ServicePlanModel model)
        {
            model = await servicePlanService!.SaveNewServicePlanAsync(model);
            var pdf = templateGenerator!.FileGenartor(model);
            return Results.File(pdf, "application/pdf", $"agreement.pdf");
        }
```

in the blazor component

I tried like this

```
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Disabled="planOfService.ServicePlanBudgetTypeModel.SupportItems == null" Class="rounded-pill"  OnClick="@(async () => await generateServiceAgreement())">Generate New Agreement</MudButton>
```

```
 private async Task generateServiceAgreement() { 
 await httpService.HttpPost<string>("service-plan", this.ServicePlanModel);
}
```

But I got below error

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: '%' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: '%' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '%' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
  at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
```